# Multi-Select File Uploader

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, file, user-controls

I'm trying to come up with a viable (and the simpler the better) solution for a multi-select file upload control. Normally this would be a breeze except for a few things...

- The user needs to be able to literally select multiple files in the dialog, NOT one by one.
- Can't use open source code. (But Javascript/JQuery is OK)
- Cant use a third-party library the Microsoft doesn't support.

(Please don't bother with "Why can't you?" comments.)

I don't have a lot of experience making my own controls. (And I'd assume if there was a simple way to do this just by modifying the "Open" control, it would be an easily found tutorial.)

Thanks.

EDIT: To answer some questions...

- I haven't tried much of anything outside of researching. Not really sure of where to start with all these limitations.
- I can't use HTML5. In fact, I need IE7 compatibility. So no multiple attribute.

Comment: According to [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.file.html) the `input type="file"` allows multiple uploads, presumably with the `multiple` attribute set.

Comment: add drag and drop upload to your search

Comment: Can't use open source code. (But Javascript/JQuery is OK), you want to say  jquery based open source permitted?

Comment: If you *have* to support IE7, you're setting yourself up for disappointment going forward. You could try [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/).

Comment: @khaled_webdev I'm just a lowly drone trying to do what is asked of me. Who am I to argue? (Sigh...)

Comment: @Ber53rker : you are the chosen one to do it hh

Comment: @Ber53rker I feel your pain, in the financial industry most banks internally still use IE6 and when you're a $4billion company and 75% of your customers are on IE6 or 7, you can't just decide to support what you want to support

Answer (score 0):

How about Telerik's [multi-file upload](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/upload/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx)?  I believe they are an MS certified partner.

-J

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a customized multi-file uploader control yourself, you have to build a rich file explorer using java script client side and then upload files using ajax technology. I think all multi-file upload components use this method. If you can't use open source or third party components, it seems you have to make it from scratch.